# A confirm dialog for PHP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a intranet for some purposes on my job, actually I'm making the login form but I need to get some kind of alert to confirm or reject the authentication.

I can log on directly but my boss ask me that, also I got a new page to inform missing fields I like to have the "alert" too.

My code until now is

```
if($response){
    echo $validar->showErrors();
}
else{
    $query="SELECT *
    FROM tblusiario
    WHERE strusuario = '".$usuario."'
    AND strpwd = '".$contrasena."'";   

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error en query de logueo");   

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    ?>
            <a href="consola.php" >Link</a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.confirmation').on('click', function() {
                        return confirm('Autenticación Valida');
                    });
                </script>
    <?php
    }
    else{
    ?>
            <a href="login.php" >Link</a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.confirmation').on('click', function() {
                        return confirm('Autenticación Valida');
                    });
                </script>
    <?php
    }

    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

`showerror()` send me to a new page with the missing fields I like to make it in a message dialog or some like.

I dont know if you can understand me I'm out of practice with my English.

Thanks for your help.